# Where is 'activity' defined in this RubyMotion code?

Tags: ruby, rubymotion

In this code, 'activity' is used but never defined. Where is it first defined? I'm confused...

https://github.com/HipByte/RubyMotionSamples/blob/master/android/Conference/app/about_fragment.rb#L4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `AboutFragment`class inherits from `Android::App::Fragment`, so the most likely answer is that `activity` is defined as an instance method on `Android::App::Fragment`.

A simplified version of how that might work is:

```
module Android   
  module App
    class Fragment
      def activity
        "Activity!"
      end
    end
  end
end

class AboutFragment < Android::App::Fragment
  def onCreateView
    puts activity # Will print "Activity!"
  end
end
```

Comment: Makes sense. I wish RubyMine would make it easy to click through to see where it's defined, cause it makes it appear undefined for some reason to my IDE

Comment: Yeah, if `Android` is getting loaded by a gem you would need to make sure RubyMine is setup to allow you to jump to definition in external libraries. (Even then it won't work 100%, but may help a bit.)